# Cordova doesn't work anymore : "unexpected end"

Tags: cordova, cmd

I'm getting this error when trying to run a cordova command.

```
C:\Users\James\Desktop\Dev\neptunus>cordova prepare -d
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Processing configuration changes for plugins.
Iterating over installed plugins: []
Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
Wrote out Android application name to "Neptunus"
[Error: Unexpected end
Line: 0
Column: 0
Char: ]
```

The same goes for "cordova run" . I've tried restarting, debugging, but in vain. Would anyone know what could be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this error as well after updating my cordova version. Removing and readding the platform resolved this for me:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Hope this helps anybody who runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your platform and add the again platform

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. ionic cordova platform add android

thats all. Enjoy your coding...